Why is this custom Eigen expression allocating?
I need to sum two vectors together, where the first vector stays the same, and the second vector is added at a changing offset and possibly length. I then need to find the maximum of the result. It looks like
v1 = default_value;
v1.segment (offset, length) += v2.segment (otherOffset, length)
return v1.maxCoeff();

Unfortunately, I need to do this many times, with changing offsets/lengths. Because in Eigen there is no way to perform an offset sum without changing v1, at each iteration I must reset v1 to its default value, over and over.
For this reason, I thought it might be worthwhile to test an expression that would "pad" v2 with zeroes, so that I could avoid all these resets and possibly gain some performance. So ideally I would do:
return (v1 + pad(v2.segment (otherOffset, length), v1.length(), offset)).maxCoeff();

The idea is that the padded expression has the same length as v1 (so we can sum them), and contains only zeroes but for the input expression, offset by a certain amount. By doing this Eigen in theory can compute the max without the need to modify a vector, hopefully saving some time.

Implementing this, I've looked at a bunch of options, and in the end because this padding seems ideally similar to the replicate functionality, I took the traits and evaluator of the Replicate class and modified them to perform the padding.
Everything seems to work, but unfortunately it seems that Eigen always allocates a temporary when I try to evaluate the expression (seen via -DEIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC). Could you help me figure out what is wrong?
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

namespace Eigen { 

template<typename MatrixType,int AskedRows,int AskedCols,int RowPad, int ColPad>
class Padder;

namespace internal {
template<typename MatrixType,int AskedRows,int AskedCols,int RowPad,int ColPad>
struct traits<Padder<MatrixType,AskedRows,AskedCols,RowPad,ColPad> >
 : traits<MatrixType>
{
  typedef typename MatrixType::Scalar Scalar;
  typedef typename traits<MatrixType>::StorageKind StorageKind;
  typedef typename traits<MatrixType>::XprKind XprKind;
  typedef typename ref_selector<MatrixType>::type MatrixTypeNested;
  typedef typename remove_reference<MatrixTypeNested>::type _MatrixTypeNested;
  enum {
    RowsAtCompileTime = AskedRows==Dynamic || RowPad == Dynamic || int(MatrixType::RowsAtCompileTime)==Dynamic
                      ? Dynamic
                      : AskedRows,
    ColsAtCompileTime = AskedCols==Dynamic || ColPad == Dynamic || int(MatrixType::ColsAtCompileTime)==Dynamic
                      ? Dynamic
                      : AskedCols,
   //FIXME we don't propagate the max sizes !!!
    MaxRowsAtCompileTime = RowsAtCompileTime,
    MaxColsAtCompileTime = ColsAtCompileTime,
    IsRowMajor = MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1 ? 1
               : MaxColsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=1 ? 0
               : (MatrixType::Flags & RowMajorBit) ? 1 : 0,
    
    // FIXME enable DirectAccess with negative strides?
    Flags = IsRowMajor ? RowMajorBit : 0
  };
};
}

template<typename MatrixType,int AskedRows,int AskedCols,int RowPad,int ColPad>
class Padder
  : public internal::dense_xpr_base< Padder<MatrixType,AskedRows,AskedCols,RowPad,ColPad> >::type
{
    typedef typename internal::traits<Padder>::MatrixTypeNested MatrixTypeNested;
    typedef typename internal::traits<Padder>::_MatrixTypeNested _MatrixTypeNested;
  public:

    typedef typename internal::dense_xpr_base<Padder>::type Base;
    EIGEN_DENSE_PUBLIC_INTERFACE(Padder)
    typedef typename internal::remove_all<MatrixType>::type NestedExpression;

    template<typename OriginalMatrixType>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline explicit Padder(const OriginalMatrixType& matrix)
      : m_matrix(matrix), m_rowAsked(AskedRows), m_colAsked(AskedCols), m_rowPad(RowPad), m_colPad(ColPad)
    {
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((internal::is_same<typename internal::remove_const<MatrixType>::type,OriginalMatrixType>::value),
                          THE_MATRIX_OR_EXPRESSION_THAT_YOU_PASSED_DOES_NOT_HAVE_THE_EXPECTED_TYPE)
      eigen_assert(AskedRows!=Dynamic && AskedCols!=Dynamic && RowPad!=Dynamic && ColPad!=Dynamic);
    }

    template<typename OriginalMatrixType>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Padder(const OriginalMatrixType& matrix, Index rowAsked, Index colAsked, Index rowPad, Index colPad)
      : m_matrix(matrix), m_rowAsked(rowAsked), m_colAsked(colAsked), m_rowPad(rowPad), m_colPad(colPad)
    {
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((internal::is_same<typename internal::remove_const<MatrixType>::type,OriginalMatrixType>::value),
                          THE_MATRIX_OR_EXPRESSION_THAT_YOU_PASSED_DOES_NOT_HAVE_THE_EXPECTED_TYPE)
    }

    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Index rows() const { return m_rowAsked.value(); }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Index cols() const { return m_colAsked.value(); }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Index rowPad() const { return m_rowPad.value(); }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Index colPad() const { return m_colPad.value(); }

    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    const _MatrixTypeNested& nestedExpression() const
    { 
      return m_matrix; 
    }

  protected:
    MatrixTypeNested m_matrix;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, AskedRows> m_rowAsked;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, AskedCols> m_colAsked;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, RowPad> m_rowPad;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, ColPad> m_colPad;
};

template<int AskedRows,int AskedCols,int RowPad,int ColPad, typename Derived>
const Padder<Derived,AskedRows,AskedCols,RowPad,ColPad>
pad(const DenseBase<Derived>& d)
{
  return Padder<Derived,AskedRows,AskedCols,RowPad,ColPad>(d.derived());
}

template<typename Derived>
const Padder<Derived,Dynamic,Dynamic,Dynamic,Dynamic>
pad(const DenseBase<Derived>& d, int rows, int cols, int rowpad, int colpad)
{
  return Padder<Derived,Dynamic,Dynamic,Dynamic,Dynamic>(d.derived(), rows, cols, rowpad, colpad);
}

namespace internal {
template<typename ArgType,int AskedRows,int AskedCols,int RowPad,int ColPad>
struct unary_evaluator<Padder<ArgType, AskedRows, AskedCols, RowPad, ColPad> >
  : evaluator_base<Padder<ArgType, AskedRows, AskedCols, RowPad, ColPad> >
{
  typedef Padder<ArgType, AskedRows, AskedCols, RowPad, ColPad> XprType;
  typedef typename XprType::CoeffReturnType CoeffReturnType;
  typedef typename internal::nested_eval<ArgType,1>::type ArgTypeNested;
  typedef typename internal::remove_all<ArgTypeNested>::type ArgTypeNestedCleaned;
  
  enum {
    CoeffReadCost = evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::CoeffReadCost,
    LinearAccessMask = XprType::IsVectorAtCompileTime ? LinearAccessBit : 0,
    Flags = (evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::Flags & (HereditaryBits|LinearAccessMask) & ~RowMajorBit) | (traits<XprType>::Flags & RowMajorBit),
    
    Alignment = evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::Alignment
  };

  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC explicit unary_evaluator(const XprType& padded)
    : m_arg(padded.nestedExpression()),
      m_argImpl(m_arg),
      m_rows(padded.nestedExpression().rows()),
      m_cols(padded.nestedExpression().cols()),
      m_rowPad(padded.rowPad()),
      m_colPad(padded.colPad())
  {}
 
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  CoeffReturnType coeff(Index row, Index col) const
  {
      if (row < m_rowPad.value() || row >= m_rowPad.value() + m_rows.value())
          return 0.0;
      if (col < m_colPad.value() || col >= m_colPad.value() + m_cols.value())
          return 0.0;
    
    return m_argImpl.coeff(row - m_rowPad.value(), col - m_colPad.value());
  }
  
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  CoeffReturnType coeff(Index index) const
  {
    Index actual_index;
    if (internal::traits<XprType>::RowsAtCompileTime==1) {
      if (index < m_rowPad.value() || index >= m_rowPad.value() + m_rows.value())
          return 0.0;
      actual_index = index - m_rowPad.value();
    } else {
      if (index < m_colPad.value() || index >= m_colPad.value() + m_cols.value())
          return 0.0;
      actual_index = index - m_colPad.value();
    }
    
    return m_argImpl.coeff(actual_index);
  }

  template<int LoadMode, typename PacketType>
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  PacketType packet(Index row, Index col) const
  {
      if (row < m_rowPad.value() || row >= m_rowPad.value() + m_rows.value())
          return 0.0;
      if (col < m_colPad.value() || col >= m_colPad.value() + m_cols.value())
          return 0.0;

    return m_argImpl.template packet<LoadMode,PacketType>(row - m_rowPad.value(), col - m_colPad.value());
  }
  
  template<int LoadMode, typename PacketType>
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  PacketType packet(Index index) const
  {
    Index actual_index;
    if (internal::traits<XprType>::RowsAtCompileTime==1) {
      if (index < m_rowPad.value() || index >= m_rowPad.value() + m_rows.value())
          return 0.0;
      actual_index = index - m_rowPad.value();
    } else {
      if (index < m_colPad.value() || index >= m_colPad.value() + m_cols.value())
          return 0.0;
      actual_index = index - m_colPad.value();
    }

    return m_argImpl.template packet<LoadMode,PacketType>(actual_index);
  }
 
protected:
  const ArgTypeNested m_arg;
  evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned> m_argImpl;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, ArgType::RowsAtCompileTime> m_rows;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, ArgType::ColsAtCompileTime> m_cols;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, RowPad> m_rowPad;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, ColPad> m_colPad;
};


}
} // end namespace Eigen

int main() {
    Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true);
    Eigen::VectorXd default_value(4);
    default_value << 10, 11, 12, 13;

    Eigen::VectorXd v1 = default_value;

    Eigen::VectorXd v2(3);
    v2 << 1, 2, 3;

    // FIRST TEST

    v1.segment (1, 2) += v2.segment (1, 2);
    std::cout << v1.transpose() << '\n';
    v1 = default_value;

    // SECOND TEST (same result)

    std::cout << (v1 + pad(v2.segment (1, 2), 4, 1, 1, 0)).transpose() << '\n';

    // MEMORY TEST (always fails no matter what is padded)

    // Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false);
    // std::cout << pad(v2, 3, 3, 0, 0) << '\n';
    // Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true);

    return 0;
}

I thought it might be due to the cost estimate, but I set typedef typename internal::nested_eval<ArgType,1>::type ArgTypeNested; in the evaluator, which I thought was enough (IIUC, this means that for each coefficient read you at most need to evaluate 1, so the cost shouldn't be bad, and so there should be no reason to create a temporary).

I think you can avoid the resetting to default and all the other stuff by writing std::max({v1.head(offset).maxCoeff(), (v1.segment(offset, length) + v2).maxCoeff(), v1.tail(v1.size() - offset - length).maxCoeff()}).

I'm not great at making custom evaluators in Eigen but the packet methods look wrong. If the offset is not a multiple of the packet size, then at the borders from padding to data, you would need to fill part of the packet with zeros and part with data, right?

It also seems to me like we could do better from an algorithmic perspective but for that I would need to know more about the whole thing. Do you scan through all possible offsets to find the highest combined possible coefficient? Is maxCoeff() just a placeholder for something more elaborate? Do you do anything else with the sum? How large are the vectors typically?

FWIW the Pad operator doesn't seem to do an allocation as you can see here in Godbolt. I think you are seeing a false positive caused by the handling of writing Eigen types to cout. However, the code is also not vectorized, which explains why the packet method stuff didn't affect the result

@Homer512 Thanks, really appreciate the help. I am considering the "manual" piecewise max, but I also thought that it would be cool to learn to write an expression just in case, and this one seemed simple enough. The packet is the same as for Replicate, maybe there is some specialization that I forgot to copy in (since it looks wrong for replicate as well), I'll look into that.

@Homer512 The algorithm is a fairly standard dynamic programming best-path evaluator, and the vector I need to add are some specific penalties for each node. I thought about it a lot and I don't think the core of the algorithm can significantly be improved. You are right that if I don't print it doesn't actually allocate, that's great! How are you testing whether packet is used or not?

If you reuse the same v1 vector a lot with different offsets and/or v2 vectors, you can simply precompute the maximum coefficient for the head and tail segments without overlap by using std::partial_sum with a max operator to get the prefix/suffix maximum. Then it's just a simple lookup instead of a linear scan for v1.head(n).maxCoeff() etc.

To see if the packet interface is used, I would simply add an assert(false) and see if it fires. Personally, I just looked at the assembly in Godbolt and saw that all instructions have the suffix sd for single double instead of pd for packed double
